# How to remove a null value from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have a JSON Feed:

```
{
    "count1" = 2;
    "count2" = 2;
    idval = 40;
    level = "<null>";
    "logo_url" = "/assets/logos/default_logo_medium.png";
    name = "Golf Club";
    "role_in_club" = Admin;
}
```

The problem is the `"<null>"`. I cannot figure out how to remove it from the NSDictionary before saving it to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Because you you can save null values to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: ah, "before saving them to NSUserDefaults" - sorry, haven't read that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40343081/2273338

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Iterate through the dictionary and look for any null entries and remove them.

```
NSMutableDictionary *prunedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString * key in [yourDictionary allKeys])
{
    if (![[yourDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        [prunedDictionary setObject:[yourDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

After that, `prunedDictionary` should have all non-null items in the original dictionary.

Comment: I wonder which is better performance-wise: Creating a mutable copy of the dictionary and then removing objects from it or adding all of the values to the dictionary manually as you are here..

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII unless the array is _very_ large it really doesn't matter.  If the array _is_ large enough for it to matter, I would just try it both ways and see which one was fastest.

Answer (score 50):

Another variation, without (explicit) loop:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [yourDictionary mutableCopy];
NSArray *keysForNullValues = [dict allKeysForObject:[NSNull null]];
[dict removeObjectsForKeys:keysForNullValues];
```

Comment: Similarly you could remove all empty entries by replacing [NSNull null] with @""

Comment: This is a cool code but what we can do if we have dictionaries into array.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my category-based recursive solution for dictionaries containing dictionaries and arrays which values can also be dictionaries and arrays:

File **NSDictionary+Dario.m**:

```
#import "NSArray+Dario.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Dario)

- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithEmptyStrings {

    const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for(NSString *key in self) {
        const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
        if(object == nul) {
            [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
        } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [replaced setObject:[object dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithEmptyStrings] forKey:key];
        } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [replaced setObject:[object arrayByReplacingNullsWithEmptyStrings] forKey:key];
        } else {
            [replaced setObject:object forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)replaced];
}

@end
```

File **NSArray+Dario.m**:

```
#import "NSDictionary+Dario.h"

@implementation NSArray (Dario)

- (NSArray *) arrayByReplacingNullsWithEmptyStrings {
    const NSMutableArray *replaced = [NSMutableArray new];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for (int i=0; i<[self count]; i++) {
        const id object = [self objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [replaced setObject:[object dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithEmptyStrings] atIndexedSubscript:i];
        } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [replaced setObject:[object arrayByReplacingNullsWithEmptyStrings] atIndexedSubscript:i];
        } else if (object == nul){
            [replaced setObject:blank atIndexedSubscript:i];
        } else {
            [replaced setObject:object atIndexedSubscript:i];
        }
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)replaced];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this for remove null from dictionary

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)recursive:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {
for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {    
    id nullString = [dictionary objectForKey:key];   
    if ([nullString isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        [self recursive:(NSMutableDictionary*)nullString];
    } else {
        if ((NSString*)nullString == (id)[NSNull null])
            [dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:key];
    }
}
return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: That replaces nulls with @"", which may or may not be what you want :-)

Comment: “[dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:key];” This may crash.

The sub/recursive dictionary maybe not mutableDictionary.

So we can use a new mutableDictionary to collection every no-null and sub-dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

To remove it, convert it into a mutable dictionary and remove the object for key "level";

```
NSDictionary* dict = ....;  // this is the dictionary to modify
NSMutableDictionary* mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
[mutableDict removeObjectForKey:@"level"];
dict = [mutableDict copy];
```

If you don't use ARC, you'll need to add some calls to 'release'.

**Update:**

If you don't know the name of the key(s) with the `"<null>"` objects, then you have to iterate:

```
NSDictionary* dict = ....;  // this is the dictionary to modify
NSMutableDictionary* mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
for (id key in dict) {
    id value = [dict objectForKey: key];
    if ([@"<null>" isEqual: value]) {
        [mutableDict removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}
dict = [mutableDict copy];
```

To locate the `"<null>"` values, I'm using a string comparison since `"<null>"` is a string in your sample. But I'm not sure if this is really the case.

Comment: That's not the case. If it was a string that wouldn't be a problem. The matter here is that the parses will produce a `NSNull` instance reading "<null>" and that value cannot be stored in the `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The sample in the question isn't JSON but most likely the NSLog output of the dictionary (after the JSON data has been parsed). If the value at key *level* was a NSNull instance, it would have printed `<null>` instead of `"<null>"`. So either the value is a string or the sample is mistaken.

Comment: Gabriella you are correct. The problem is that it is getting a value stored as "<null>" and it cannot recognise it. usually it gives me a value like null.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is the most resource saving way

// category implementation on NSDictionary

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByRemovingNullValues {

    NSMutableDictionary * d;
    for (NSString * key in self) {

        if (self[key] == [NSNull null]) {
            if (d == nil) {
                d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
            }
            [d removeObjectForKey:key];
        }

    }

    if (d == nil) {
        return self;
    }

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a category for NSJSOn serialisation class.

Create a category and import class to use its methods...

```
// Mutable containers are required to remove nulls.
if (replacingNulls)
{
    // Force add NSJSONReadingMutableContainers since the null removal depends on it.
    opt = opt || NSJSONReadingMutableContainers;
}

id JSONObject = [self JSONObjectWithData:data options:opt error:error];

if ((error && *error) || !replacingNulls)
{
    return JSONObject;
}

[JSONObject recursivelyReplaceNullsIgnoringArrays:ignoreArrays withString:replaceString];
return JSONObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution for your question and i got it

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"count1",@"2",@"count2",@"40",@"idval",@"<null>",@"level",@"/assets/logos/default_logo_medium.png",@"logo_url",@"Golf Club",@"name",@"role_in_club",@"Admin", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
    if ([dict[key] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        mutableDict[key] = @""; 
    }
    if([dict[key] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
    {
        mutableDict[key] = @"";
    }
}
dict = [mutableDict copy];
NSLog(@"The dict is - %@",dict);
```

Finally the answer is

```
The dict is - {
Admin = "role_in_club";
count1 = 2;
count2 = 2;
idval = 40;
level = "";
"logo_url" = "/assets/logos/default_logo_medium.png";
name = "Golf Club";
}
```

Comment: I tried and after that then only I posted my answer with result.It works.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing in this way.

```
NSMutableDictionary *prunedDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
  if (![obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    prunedDict[key] = obj;
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is ok when the result is in array or dictionary , you can change the result returned to  nil or empty string by editing the code

the function is recursive  , so can parse array in dictionary .

```
-(id)changeNull:(id)sender{
    
    id newObj;
    
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

        NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        
        for (id item in sender){
        
            [newArray addObject:[self changeNull:item]];
        
        }
        
        newObj = newArray;
    }
    
    else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        
        for (NSString *key in sender){
            
            NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary*)sender;
            
            
            id item = oldDict[key];

            if (![item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && ![item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

                if ([item isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
                    item = @"";
                    
                }
                
                [newDict setValue:item forKey:key];

            }
            else{
                
                [newDict setValue:[self changeNull:item] forKey:key];
                
            }
        }
        newObj = newDict;
    }
    
    return newObj;
}
```

resulting in:

```
jsonresult (
    {
        Description = "<null>";
        Id = 1;
        Name = High;
    },
        {
        Description = "<null>";
        Id = 2;
        Name = Medium;
    },
        {
        Description = "<null>";
        Id = 3;
        Name = Low;
    }
)

change null (
    {
        Description = "";
        Id = 1;
        Name = High;
    },
        {
        Description = "";
        Id = 2;
        Name = Medium;
    },
        {
        Description = "";
        Id = 3;
        Name = Low;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Swift 3.0/4.0` Solution

Following is the solution, when `JSON` have `sub-dictionaries`. This will go-through all the `dictionaries`, sub`-dictionaries` of `JSON` and remove `NULL(NSNull) key-value` pair from the `JSON`.

```
extension Dictionary {

    func removeNull() -> Dictionary {
        let mainDict = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: self)
        for _dict in mainDict {
            if _dict.value is NSNull {
                mainDict.removeObject(forKey: _dict.key)
            }
            if _dict.value is NSDictionary {
                let test1 = (_dict.value as! NSDictionary).filter({ $0.value is NSNull }).map({ $0 })
                let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: _dict.value as! NSDictionary)
                for test in test1 {
                    mutableDict.removeObject(forKey: test.key)
                }
                mainDict.removeObject(forKey: _dict.key)
                mainDict.setValue(mutableDict, forKey: _dict.key as? String ?? "")
            }
            if _dict.value is NSArray {
                let mutableArray = NSMutableArray.init(object: _dict.value)
                for (index,element) in mutableArray.enumerated() where element is NSDictionary {
                    let test1 = (element as! NSDictionary).filter({ $0.value is NSNull }).map({ $0 })
                    let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: element as! NSDictionary)
                    for test in test1 {
                        mutableDict.removeObject(forKey: test.key)
                    }
                    mutableArray.replaceObject(at: index, with: mutableDict)
                }
                mainDict.removeObject(forKey: _dict.key)
                mainDict.setValue(mutableArray, forKey: _dict.key as? String ?? "")
            }
        }
        return mainDict as! Dictionary<Key, Value>
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my answer. Actually the embeded link’s answer is also posted by me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 3 methods in your view controller, and call this method like this way

```
NSDictionary *dictSLoginData = [self removeNull:[result valueForKey:@"data"]];

- (NSDictionary*)removeNull:(NSDictionary *)dict {

    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: dict];

    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {

        const id object = [dict objectForKey: key];
        if (object == nul) {
            [replaced setObject: blank forKey: key];
        } else if([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
            [replaced setObject: [self replaceNull:object] forKey: key];
        } else if([object isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {
            [replaced setObject: [self replaceNullArray:object] forKey: key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: replaced];
}

- (NSArray *)replaceNullArray:(NSArray *)array {

    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    NSMutableArray *replaced = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

    for (int i=0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        const id object = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        if (object == nul) {
            [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:blank];
        } else if([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
            [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[self replaceNull:object]];
        } else if([object isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {
            [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[self replaceNullArray:object]];
        }
    }
    return replaced;
}

- (NSDictionary *)replaceNull:(NSDictionary *)dict {

    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: dict];

    for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
        const id object = [dict objectForKey: key];
        if (object == nul) {
            [replaced setObject: blank forKey: key];
        } else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
            [replaced setObject: [self replaceNull:object] forKey: key];
        } else if([object isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {
            [replaced setObject: [self replaceNullArray:object] forKey: key];
        }
    }
    return replaced;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify @sinh99 answer. Use a new  NSMutableDictionary to collection no-null values and sub-dictionary values.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)recursiveRemoveNullValues:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSMutableDictionary *mDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        id nullString = [dictionary objectForKey:key];

        if ([nullString isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *mDictionary_sub = [self recursiveRemoveNullValues:(NSDictionary*)nullString];
            [mDictionary setObject:mDictionary_sub forKey:key];
        } else {

            if ((NSString*)nullString == (id)[NSNull null]) {
                [mDictionary setValue:@"" forKey:key];
            } else {
                [mDictionary setValue:nullString forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }

    return mDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift - Nested `NSNull` supported

First of all, we use `Dictionary` in Swift instead of `NSDictionary`.

To remove **any** `NSNull` appearance in any nested level (including **arrays** and **dictionaries**), try this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    func removeNullsFromDictionary() -> Self {
        var destination = Self()
        for key in self.keys {
            guard !(self[key] is NSNull) else { destination[key] = nil; continue }
            guard !(self[key] is Self) else { destination[key] = (self[key] as! Self).removeNullsFromDictionary() as? Value; continue }
            guard self[key] is [Value] else { destination[key] = self[key]; continue }

            let orgArray = self[key] as! [Value]
            var destArray: [Value] = []
            for item in orgArray {
                guard let this = item as? Self else { destArray.append(item); continue }
                destArray.append(this.removeNullsFromDictionary() as! Value)
            }
            destination[key] = destArray as? Value
        }
        return destination
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that the key of the dictionary should be `String`</sub>